# Is there a better way to merge row data based on criteria (Google Apps Script)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, google-apps-script, optimization

Alright...Let me start by saying I am self-taught with Google Apps Script...enough said, right!?  The script below is functioning but I want to optimize it or come up with another way to achieve the same result.  The script takes 18000 rows and 86 columns of data and combines them into a single rows based on an id list.  The id list is about 13000 rows long.  The short version is this...it filters the data by the id and then checks each column for the last row with submitted data and returns that cell.  For example:

```
//sample data
[[311112, 1, 2, 4, 5,"","","","","","", 2, 3],
[323223,"","","","","", 2, 4, 4,"","","",""],
[321321, 1, 2, 4, 5,"","","","","","", 2, 3],
[311112, 4, 1, 6, 7,"", 3,"", 3,"","", 5, 3],
[321233,"","","","","","", 4, 3, 1, 5,"",""],
[321321,"","","","","","","","", 1 ,4,"",""],
[323223,"","","","","", 2, 3,"","","","",""],
[323153,"", 2, 3, 6,"","","","","","","",""],
[321321,"","","","","", 2, 3,"","","","",""],
[321321,"", 5, 3,"", 1,"","","","","","",""]]

//filtered Data by id 321321
[[321321, 1, 2, 4, 5,"","","","","","", 2, 3],
[321321,"","","","","","","","", 1, 4,"",""],
[321321,"","","","","", 2, 3,"","","","",""],
[321321,"", 5, 3,"", 1,"","","","","","",""]]

// returned row is getting the last nonempty value for each column from the filtered data.

[[321321, 1, 5, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3,"", 1, 4, 2, 3]]
```

**It takes about *16-18 minutes* for the script to complete.  Is there a better way to accomplish this or any optimizations suggestions?**

```
function combineR(startRow, startRange) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var testSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Raw Scores');
  var cSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Combined Scores');
  var gradingResults = testSheet.getRange(1, 1, testSheet.getLastRow(), testSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  if (startRow > cSheet.getLastRow()) {
    return;
  }

  if (startRow + startRange > cSheet.getLastRow()) {
    startRange = cSheet.getLastRow() - startRow;
  }

  var sID = cSheet.getRange(startRow, 2, startRange).getValues();
  var maxScores = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < sID.length; x++) {
    var filtered = gradingResults.filter(function (dataRow) {
      return dataRow[0] === sID[x][0];
    });

    if (isFinite(filtered)) {
      maxScores.push(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
        '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
        '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
        '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
        '', '', '', '', '']);
      continue;
    } else {
      maxScores.push(['', getMaxLetter(filtered, 3), lastGraded(filtered, 4), lastGraded(filtered, 5), lastGraded(filtered, 6), lastGraded(filtered, 7), lastGraded(filtered, 8), lastGraded(filtered, 9), lastGraded(filtered, 10), lastGraded(filtered, 11),
        lastGraded(filtered, 12), lastGraded(filtered, 13), lastGraded(filtered, 14), lastGraded(filtered, 15), lastGraded(filtered, 16), lastGraded(filtered, 17), lastGraded(filtered, 18), lastGraded(filtered, 19), lastGraded(filtered, 20), lastGraded(filtered, 21),
        lastGraded(filtered, 22), lastGraded(filtered, 23), lastGraded(filtered, 24), lastGraded(filtered, 25), lastGraded(filtered, 26), lastGraded(filtered, 27), lastGraded(filtered, 28), lastGraded(filtered, 29), lastGraded(filtered, 30), lastGraded(filtered, 31),
        lastGraded(filtered, 32), lastGraded(filtered, 33), lastGraded(filtered, 34), lastGraded(filtered, 35), lastGraded(filtered, 36), lastGraded(filtered, 37), lastGraded(filtered, 38), lastGraded(filtered, 39), lastGraded(filtered, 40), lastGraded(filtered, 41),
        lastGraded(filtered, 42), lastGraded(filtered, 43), lastGraded(filtered, 44), lastGraded(filtered, 45), lastGraded(filtered, 46)]);
    }
  }
  cSheet.getRange(startRow, 11, maxScores.length, maxScores[0].length).setValues(maxScores)
}

function getMaxLetter(arr, idx) {
  var letter = arr.map(function (e) { return e[idx] }).sort().pop();
  return letter;
}

function lastGraded(arr, idx) {
  var newArray = arr.map(function (e) { return e[idx] });
  newArray.reverse();
  for (var x = 0; x < newArray.length; x++) {
    if (typeof newArray[x] == 'number') {
      return newArray[x];
    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

Column A has duplicate Ids that need to be merged
[image: Raw Data]

Column B has the unique values that are the final merged product
[image: Combined Data]

Comment: Sample screenshot of two sheets please.

Comment: In your example, I'm not understanding how the sample data yields the returned row. Could you please clarify that? Maybe the screenshot will help with that.

Comment: Currently, this is accomplished by filtering the data by Id then taking that specific column and building a list that finds the last nonempty entry.  From my example, the first element is blank in every set other than the first so it returns 1 since it is the "last" nonempty submission with data. Clear as mud...right?

Comment: @TheMaster Screenshots added.

Comment: I can understand about the logic of your top sample table. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about the differences of your 2 images. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I also can understand the logic of the first table, but the screen shots mention duplicate Ids and unique values which seem to be referring to another process entirely, which is confusing. Can you clarify how the first example is related to the second?

Comment: My apologies!  I will update the first example to show what the script is doing for all of the steps.

Comment: @iansedano The first example has been updated.

Comment: @Tanaike I updated the first example to try to clarify.  As for the details...The project is taking form submissions, scoring the submissions based on criteria, and then this part that I shared is used to combine all submissions into a unique table based on the id found in one of the columns to show each rows current levels.

Comment: Could you update the sample above 1. to be a syntactically valid 2D array.  2.  Use `""` instead of a empty space (as that is how arrays are returned from spreadsheet)

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. But unfortunately, I cannot still understand about the differences of your 2 images. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issues:

The script seems to have various issues, but the main issue seems to be calling `lastGraded` function many times with various indexes. This does `map`, `reverse` and everything else for each index and costs time.

#### Solution:

Given  your sample data, I propose the following approach:

- Get all the input data in 1 2D array
- [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)  the input data to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). The map will have each `id` as `key` and  all the rows that match that `key` as 2D `array` for each `key`. This  will greatly increase performance/speed at the cost of memory. This is better than filtering the array by each id, because,

  - You loop the input array only once
  - whereas `arr.filter` will have to loop the array for each id
- Once reduced to a `map`, Loop through each `array` in the `map` in the reverse  for each element in the last row to find the non empty element.

#### Sample snippet:

```js
const arrMain =
  //sample data
  [
    [311112, 1, 2, 4, 5, '', '', '', '', '', '', 2, 3],
    [323223, '', '', '', '', '', 2, 4, 4, '', '', '', ''],
    [321321, 1, 2, 4, 5, '', '', '', '', '', '', 2, 3],
    [311112, 4, 1, 6, 7, '', 3, '', 3, '', '', 5, 3],
    [321233, '', '', '', '', '', '', 4, 3, 1, 5, '', ''],
    [321321, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 1, 4, '', ''],
    [323223, '', '', '', '', '', 2, 3, '', '', '', '', ''],
    [323153, '', 2, 3, 6, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    [321321, '', '', '', '', '', 2, 3, '', '', '', '', ''],
    [321321, '', 5, 3, '', 1, '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
  ];

//reduce input array to a map of id=>rows
const map = arrMain.reduce((map, row) => {
  if (!map.has(row[0])) map.set(row[0], [row]);
  else map.get(row[0]).push(row);
  return map;
}, new Map());

const out = [];
map.forEach(arr2d => {
  const l = arr2d.length - 1,
    lastRow = arr2d[l].slice(0);
  //iterate lastrow of this id's column elements
  for (let j = 0; j < lastRow.length; ++j) {
    if (lastRow[j] === '') {
      //iterate each row of this id
      for (let i = l; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (arr2d[i][j] !== '') {
          lastRow[j] = arr2d[i][j];
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  out.push(lastRow);
});
console.log(out);
```

Comment: Thank you for that!  I had no idea that .filter was so costly in run time.  Google Apps Script didn't run a couple of things from your sample but I was able to walk through your logic and modify my script to work.  Switching from .filter to .reduce has decreased the run time from 16.5 minutes to 9.75 minutes.  This is much more acceptable!  Thanks again for taking to time to walk me through that!

Comment: @OneInAMillion `filter` is not the main cost. It is this: `maxScores.push(['', getMaxLetter(filtered, 3), lastGraded(filtered, 4), lastGraded(filtered, 5), lastGraded(filtered, 6), lastGraded(filtered, 7), lastGraded(filtered, 8), lastGraded(filtered, 9), lastGraded(filtered, 10), lastGraded(filtered, 11),
        lastGraded(filtered, 12), lastGrade....` For each `lastGraded` call, you're `map`ping and `reverse`ing and `looping` the same array unnecessarily. Your script would run in order of seconds if you use my method or at least find a way to call lastGraded only once

Comment: @OneInAMillion What do you mean by *Google Apps Script didn't run a couple of things from your sample* ?  Upgrade to v8, if you haven't done already. My sample is fully  compatible with apps script v8 engine.

Comment: Clearly I have much to learn.  V8 did not error out as you stated.

Comment: As for the cost, I agree, I am looping the same array unnecessarily...The data set contains more columns than needed and the columns are not in the correct order.  Now that I say that...I should have thought of this.  I just need to clean up the data I call before I push it through your approach.  Thanks again for the info!

Comment: @OneInAMillion You may ask a specific question about that for ideas/logic/algo with sample data

Comment: Ok, I just applied that to my data and WOW!!!  What took me 16-18 minutes to process is now down to 55-75 seconds!  Amazing!!!  You clearly are TheMaster!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221854/discussion-between-oneinamillion-and-themaster).